# PHP: Array removed specifed keys from the array variable

Tags: php

I have an array, the array key contains the file name and array value will be another array which contain sfile size,date etc.

In these array list, I want to store only **xls** and **xlsx** files alone. I need to remove files of all other extensions.

Is there any predefined function in PHP?

Note: i have constant variable this varaible contain the like VAR_FILE_EXT= "xls, xlsx, csv"

```
[sample.xls] => Array (
            [size] => 3353
            [uid] => 1012
            [gid] => 1013
            [permissions] => 33188
            [atime] => 1338497357
            [mtime] => 1338497357
            [type] => 1
        )

[sample.csv] => Array (
            [size] => 3353
            [uid] => 1012
            [gid] => 1013
            [permissions] => 33188
            [atime] => 1338497357
            [mtime] => 1338497357
            [type] => 1
        )

[sample.txt] => Array (
            [size] => 3353
            [uid] => 1012
            [gid] => 1013
            [permissions] => 33188
            [atime] => 1338497357
            [mtime] => 1338497357
            [type] => 1
        )
```

in this example i want remove only sample.txt array keys and its corresponding values.

Comment: How do you store your file names?

Comment: yes, only after these validation

Comment: I mean are there stored in some array with keys having file names eg. `array('sample.xls'=>array(...), 'sample.csv'=>array(...)`?

Comment: Instead of removing unwanted entries - why are you adding them? Always try to fix the reason, not hide the symptoms. (if you have control about the building of the array.)

Comment: i am using the phpseclib library, in this lib there is function called rawlist, which returns all files in the directory

Comment: Basically it is not possible without iterating over the array, which you say you do not want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$filtered = array_intersect_key(
    $array,
    array_filter(array_keys($array), function ($name) { return preg_match('/\.xlsx?$/', $name); })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$your_array = array(
    'sample.xls' => ...
    'sample.csv' => ...
    'sample.txt' => ...
);

$extensions = '/('.str_replace(', ', '|', $VAR_FILE_EXT).')$/i';
$new_array = array();

foreach ($your_array as $file => $stuff) {
    if (preg_match($extensions, $file)) {
        $new_array[$file] => $stuff;
    }
}
```

Then you use $new_array.

Comment: so if i have 1000 files in array, then loop will round for 1000 times.  as well i dont want pregmatch here, withjust path to i can get extension .... but i dont want to round 1000 time, i want to use some array function with ext as argument, that should take of filteration

Comment: You have to loop. Even if you use a function that PHP provides, it will loop over the array. What you can do is, if you only need the array once, is to do your process inside the "foreach" of the code I provided. Then you won't need to loop twice (one to filter, another to process the array).